# curiosity on d3's selectAll method

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom, selector, selectall

I am trying to understand how d3's methods work. I think I've been quite getting d3, basic level of course, but there is one weird thing about selectAll method I don't understand. So when I try to create and append dom nodes to selected dom element, no matter it exists or not, sometimes it creates four nodes or two, or six on the other cases. To make the question clear, I am going to use simple examples.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <svg></svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
    dummyData = [
         {
           name: 'A',
           age: 50
         },
         {
           name: 'B',
           age: 20
         }
       ]

    svg = d3.select('svg')
            .attr('width','500')
            .attr('height', '300')
          .append('g')
            .attr('transform','translate(40, 40)');


function example_1() {

    svg.selectAll('circle')
      .data(dummyData)
      .enter()
    .append('circle')
      .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.age}, 20)`)
      .attr('cx',32).attr('cy',53)
      .attr('r',15);

 }


function example_2() {

    svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(dummyData)
      .enter()
    .append('circle')
      .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.age}, 20)`)
      .attr('cx',32)
      .attr('cy',53)
      .attr('r',15);
}

function example_3() {

    svg.selectAll('div')  // This div is an arbitrary value. It can be any html tag to output the same result 
      .data(dummyData)
      .enter()
    .append('circle')
      .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.age}, 20)`)
      .attr('cx',32)
      .attr('cy',53)
      .attr('r',15);

 }

function example_4() {

   svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(dummyData)
      .enter()
    .append('circle')
      .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.age}, 20)`)
      .attr('cx',32)
      .attr('cy',53)
      .attr('r',15);

    svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(dummyData)
      .enter()
    .append('path')
      .attr('stroke','#000')
      .attr('d',`M5,5H500`)
}

function example_5() {

   svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(dummyData)
      .enter()
    .append('circle')
      .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.age}, 20)`)
      .attr('cx',32)
      .attr('cy',53)
      .attr('r',15);

    svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(dummyData)
      .enter()
    .append('g')
    .append('path')
      .attr('stroke','#000')
      .attr('d',`M5,5H500`)
}


example_1(); // This one creates DOM as: 

<svg>
  <g>
    <circle></circle>
    <circle></circle>
  </g>
</svg>

example_2(); // This one creates DOM as:

<svg>
  <g>
    <circle></circle>
    <circle></circle>
    <circle></circle>
    <circle></circle>
  </g>
</svg>

example_3(); // This one creates DOM as:

<svg>
  <g>
    <circle></circle>
    <circle></circle>
    <circle></circle>
    <circle></circle>
  </g>
</svg>

example_4(); // This one creates DOM as:

<svg>
  <g>
    <circle></circle>
    <circle></circle>
    <path></path>
    <path></path>
    <circle></circle>
    <circle></circle>
    <path></path>
    <path></path>
  </g>
</svg>

example_5(); // This one creates DOM as:

<svg>
  <g>
    <circle></circle>
    <circle></circle>
    <g>
      <path></path>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The variable, svg, is a dom node g as a child of svg in my example. Which means it does have neither a circle nor g nor div as its child. Then what is the selectAll method is used for ? Why can we not just write as

```
svg.data(dummyData)
  .enter()
.append('circle')
  .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.age}, 20)`)
  .attr('cx',32).attr('cy',53)
  .attr('r',15);
```

Although I have tried with more different examples, it all behaves differently, but I really can't see what's happening behind the scene.
Please help me to understand at least a little. I am very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's answer your last question first.  Why can't you:

```
svg.data(dummyData).enter()
```

`d3` is using an enter, update, exit pattern.  There's tons of reading out there on the pattern and I highly recommend you study up on it.  But the quickie is this, it's not just about creating the initial elements but also updating them later.  `.selectAll` is find me all the elements matching my selector.  `.data` is bind the data to them.  `.enter` is tell me all the data elements that **were not** in my `.selectAll`.  So, the answer to your question becomes, without a `.selectAll`, there's no way for `d3` to calculate which data is **entering** and nothing is appended.  In the classic usage, on an initial rendering, the `.selectAll` returns empty (none of them exist yet), so they are all entering.

Now, with the basics, let's follow your example 5:

```
svg.selectAll('g') //<-- no gs exist in svg
  .data(dummyData)
  .enter() //<-- so, since data is two elements
.append('circle') //<-- you get two circles
  .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.age}, 20)`)
  .attr('cx',32)
  .attr('cy',53)
  .attr('r',15);

svg.selectAll('g') //<-- no gs still exist in svg
  .data(dummyData)
  .enter() //<-- so since data is two elements
.append('g') //<-- you get two gs
.append('path') //<-- each with a path under them
  .attr('stroke','#000')
  .attr('d',`M5,5H500`)
```

Now, what you are doing doesn't really make sense here. Why select `g` if you care about circles?  Usually, I wouldn't even recommend selecting elements at all. If I want a **circle to represent each of my datum**, I would do something like:

```
svg.selectAll('.my_cool_circle')
  .data(dummyData)
  .enter()
.append('circle')
.attr('class', 'my_cool_circle')
...
```

By using a class, I know that those circles are the circles represent my `dummyData`.  Also, if I need to come back later an *update* my circles (because my data is now:

```
dummyData = [
     {
       name: 'A',
       age: 50
     },
     {
       name: 'B',
       age: 20
     },
     {
       name: 'C',
       age: 30
     }          
   ]
```

).

Then:

```
 svg.selectAll('.my_cool_circle')
  .data(dummyData)
  .enter()
```

Would only return the 'C' datum and I'd only append 1 new circle.

Comment: I think I get the point a bit. I might have to try more cases to fully understand. thank you very much.

Comment: just one more question.. when I simply write svg.append('circle').attr('cx',32).attr('cy',53).attr('r',15); somehow it renders three circles at same position. why is that..?

Comment: @JayJeong, can you elaborate?  When I run [that code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mv9xveQt9ydJ820CbTeM?p=preview), I get 1 circle.

Comment: ohhhh I am actually using d3 with react.js. and I just found out that I called the render method within componentDidUpdate method as well as componentDidMount method.